# Elastic routing problem when querying by id

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 7.12, and I have simple ES code snippet as follows. I have specified the `routing` parameter when I create a document,but I didn't specify the `routing` when I query it with id, , I didn't find the doc.
I would ask how query by id works, does it spread the query to all the shards  or just to the shard that the doc belongs to(the id acts as routing if no routing is specified).

```
PUT /lib4
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 4,
    "number_of_replicas": 2,
  
  }
}

#create the doc with routing parameter
PUT /lib4/_doc/4?routing=xyz
{
  "name":"abcd"
}


#no documents found
GET /lib4/_doc/4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [`routing`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) parameter at the time of [retrieving the document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#get-routing) by `id`. As the routing parameter targets the respective primary shard and fetches the document.

Modify your `GET API` call as

```
GET /lib4/_doc/4??routing=xyz
```

Comment: Thanks @escoder for the helpful answer, I understood.

Answer (score 1):

By default when you query by id, elasticsearch uses the id for the routing

So `GET /lib4/_doc/4` is `GET /lib4/_doc/4?routing=4` behind the scenes

> If routing is used during indexing, the routing value also needs to be specified to retrieve a document.
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#get-routing

Comment: Thanks @escoder for the helpful answer, I understood.